# How would you plot this equation (in the complex plane)?

Tags: integration, graphing-functions, contour-integration

So I am currently looking at how to calculate the integral of a complex function $f(z)$ within a contour $\gamma$. That is, an integral of the form
$$
\int_{\gamma} f(z) \; dz
$$
Where the contour is given as a function in terms of $t$.

Say that we have a contour given by the equation
$$
\gamma (t) = r \; e^{2 \pi i t} \quad 0 \leq t \leq 1
$$

Then this contour is a circle or radius 2, once anti-clockwise about the origin.

Why is this the case? How would a function of this form be plotted, and how do we determine the direction of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\gamma(t)=re^{2\pi i t}=r\cos(2\pi t)+ir\sin(2\pi t)$, we can plot the curve just as in calculus, in the plane with $(r\cos(2\pi t),r\sin(2\pi t))$.  If you plot this, you'll see its a circle centered at the origin of radius $r$.

To figure the direction, you could take the derivative, $\gamma'(t)=2\pi i re^{2\pi i t}$.  At $t=0$, the corresponding point on the circle is $(r,0)$.  Moreover, $\gamma'(0)=2\pi i r$, which is vertical in the complex plane.  Therefore, the direction of the curve is pointing upwards; the direction is counterclockwise around the circle.